# Asp.net MVC5 with E.F returns IQueryable or IEnumerable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

Hi everyone please help me to understand about asp.net mvc5 with e.f 6 is used  IQueryable or IEnumerable by default? I want to work using IQueryable because it is best for underlying database. I am using LINQ to entity approach and var keyword for holding linq results. By default my model classes is of type public  className {get; set} so here  returns  IQueryable or IEnumerable?
kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

`DbContext` is the context on which you access your data store when working with EF6. You access your models (tables) on the `DbContext` instance using properties of type `DbSet<TEntity>` or method `Set<TEntity>` which also returns a `DbSet<TEntity>`. `DbSet<TEntity>` implements abstract class `DbQuery<TEntity>` which implements interfaces:

- `DbQuery<TEntity>`
- `IDbSet<TEntity>`
- `IQueryable<TEntity>`
- `IEnumerable<TEntity>`
- `IQueryable`
- `IEnumerable`.

Finally if you also look at the definition for `IQueryable` you will see it is an extension of `IEnumerable`. Also `IQueryable<TEntity>` implements `IEnumerable<TEntity>`.

Comment: your are right but how can i know it is returning IQueryable or IEnumerable

Comment: @AijazAli - please define `it`. What is the thing you are talking about that returns the `IQueryable or IEnumerable`?

Comment: var addressesList = (from addresses in db.address
                                 where (addresses.full_address.StartsWith(q.Trim()) ||
                                 q == null ||
                                 addresses.full_address.EndsWith(q.Trim()))
                                 orderby addresses.id
                                 select addresses); here the return type of addressesList is IQueryable or IEnumerable ?

Comment: @AijazAli - The result is an object that implements `IQueryable<Address>` (*assuming that `Address` is the type of the instance you have selected in your select clause*). As `IQueryable<Address>` extends `IEnumerable<Address>` it is also an implementation of the `IEnumerable<Address>` interface.

Comment: @AijazAli - also see [Queryable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.select(v=vs.100).aspx) documentation.

Comment: thanks you mean that our <DbSet> implements both IQueryable and IEnumerable? Well, thanks for your valuables comments :)